# Change mytheorem-environment style

Tags: environments, theorems

In my code I create `mytheorem`-`environment`, but I'd like to improve and edit `mytheorem` so that the output of

```
\begin{mytheorem}{Pitagora}{Pitagora}
Statement of Pitagorean Theorem, \ldots
\end{mytheorem}
```

is the Theorem 1.2.

Is it possible?

I hope my question is clear.

Thank you so much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}{\@endpefalse}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endproof}{\@endpefalse}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[within=section, spaceabove=\topsep, notefont = {--- $\bigl($\normalfont\bfseries$\bigl)$}, bodyfont=\bfseries, postheadspace=\newline]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle, name=Theorem]{theorem}

\usepackage{stix}

% \newtheoremstyle{break}
%   {\topsep}{\topsep}%
%   {\itshape}{}%
%   {\bfseries}{}%
%   {\newline}{}%

% \theoremstyle{remark}

\newenvironment{statement}[1]{\textsc{Statement}$\:\:\smallblacktriangleright\:\:${#1}}

% \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newenvironment{mytheorem}[2]{\begin{theorem}[#1] \label{#2} \noindent \ignorespacesafterend \vspace{-7mm} \end{theorem}}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposizione}[section]

\newenvironment{myproposition}[2]{\begin{proposition} [#1] \label{#2} \noindent \ignorespacesafterend \end{proposition}}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\newenvironment{mylemma}[2]{\begin{lemma}[#1]\label{#2} \noindent \ignorespacesafterend \end{lemma}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{mytheorem}{Pitagora}{Pitagora}
Statement of Pitagorean Theorem, \ldots
\end{mytheorem}

\vspace{5mm}\noindent
\textbf{Theorem 1.1 --- $\bigl($Pitagora$\bigr) $}\\
Statement of Pitagorean Theorem, \ldots

\end{document}
```